# How can I use Spark to check if two HDFS datasets are equal?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

For example, I have two Spark job's outputs: a: part-00000 part-00001... part-00099, b: part-00000 part-00001... part-00099.

Is there a easy way to test whether the a equals to b regardless of the lines' order. Notice that, the spark partition order are not the same, so for part-00000 in a and b might different even if the a equals to b.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could calculate the intersect of two dataframes (common lines) and check its size:

```
val df1 = spark.read.parquet("file1")
val df2 = spark.read.parquet("file2")
val equal = df1.count == df2.count && df2.count == df1.intersect(df2).count
```